# Difference between the two areas under the curve

Tags: analysis

http://puu.sh/gy4Ez/5661d4cabd.png

My only thought is that as $$x\rightarrow\infty, y=0$$ $$y\rightarrow\infty, x=0$$ I'm not so sure that the answer is really that though. Any other thoughts would be great.

Comment: What does $x>\infty$ mean? That seems wrong.

Comment: Perhaps the OP means to use $\to$

Comment: I think it's supposed to mean that as $x\to\infty$, $y\to 0$ and vice versa.

Comment: Look at the leftmost yellow point on the curve and draw a horizontal line from there to the vertical axis.  This divides the green area into two new areas, one of which looks qualitatively the same as the yellow and one of which is finite.   In other words, the only difference between the green and yellow areas is a finite rectangle.  This is turn means that in terms of the obvious questions you might ask ("Can this area be infinite?"  "Can this area be finite?"), there's no difference between the green and the yellow.

Comment: Yeah they were supposed to be arrows.

So what you are suggesting looks like this? I think I understand. So I suppose the difference is really that there is no difference in terms of infinite space.

http://puu.sh/gy60M/a68c3edf8a.png

Comment: It seems to me that whether the tails are both of infinite area, or both finite, or one infinite and one finite, depends on how well to scale this graph was drawn and how the tails get extended beyond the graph. No formula, no good way to compute area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you say is ok, but the problem asks about *areas*, you are referring to $x$ or $y$.

It is the *x-limits* of green and yellow areas under curve that are changing in each case.

If the x-coordinate where colors change is x=a,then these these areas are respectively

$$ \int_0^a y dx $$ and

$$ \int_a^∞ y dx. $$

Comment: I agree, this what I was missing. My comments earlier help to explain the graph, but this is a more quantitative addition to it.